One-liner to specify many variables for "del" and ignore those that don't exist
I am using Spyder for exploratory data analysis -- not for production code.  I like to think of my script as a sequence of major sections.  At the end of each section, I want to delete the temporary objects so that the Variable Explorer in Spyder isn't too crowded.  However, the objects that exist depend on the control flow through the code.  If I have just one "del" statement at the end of each section to delete all objects that may come into existence regardless of the control flow through the code, I get NameError for those objects that haven't been created.
Is there a simple one-liner that I can use, similar to del a,b,c,d but not yielding an error if some of the variables don't exist?  I want a short one-liner because I don't want to take attention away from the main functions of the code.
A try/exception block is a multi-line control structure that contributes too much cognitive noise to the code, in my opinion.  Something like the following doesn't seem legal, and it seems to be that a one-liner can't consist of an if-statement within a for-loop:
# Syntax error at the "if"
for vName in ['gbCluster']: if vName in locals(): del locals()[vName]

# Works without "if"
for vName in ['gbCluster']: del locals()[vName]


I’m not familiar with Spyder – is it important that it’s one line so that you can retrieve it from history search, or…? Anyway, globals().pop(vName, None) in your loop is a typical way to delete a key only if it exists.

Beside the point, but you're not supposed to modify locals(). Use globals() instead.

@wjandrea: Thanks!  Your comment prompted me to learn that the REPL's namespace is global, as described here

@Ry: Thanks! I don't suppose that a for-loop can be avoided for popping multiple variables/objects?  Afternote: Seems impossible.    I guess the loop variable will linger without an additional del.  No biggy.  Did you want to post your comment as the answer?

{globals().pop(k, None) for k in 'abcd'} won't leave a loop variable in namespace.

"At the end of each section, I want to delete the temporary objects so that the Variable Explorer in Spyder isn't too crowded" Have you considered just using a series of functions? Pass the vars you want to keep from one block to the next as parameters (or global variables), and define the rest in the scope of the function.

@tobias_k: I find that for exploratory data analysis, I am often rejigging code, so I would like to avoid the extra constantly rejigging the function signatures and function calls.

@wim: Thanks!  That's perfect!  (Not as good as an error-less del command, but such a command doesn't exist).  Worth posting as an answer?

I do not answer questions asking for one-liners, on principle. And I think the answer you accepted is much better, anyway.

@wim: OK.  Well, here's the code pattern I used based on your example: _={globals().pop(vNm,None) for vNm in ('cat','horse') }.  Assignment to _ hides the output from the Spyder Explorer.

Use a function! You can pass in the namespace (dict) that you want names (keys) deleted from, and the function can do the heavy lifting of deleting and ignoring errors. You can then put the function in a module for reuse.
By the way, the names you want to delete are globals, not locals per se (and anyway you shouldn't modify locals()).
def del_keys_noerror(d, *keys):
    for key in keys:
        try:
            del d[key]
        except KeyError:
            pass  # Ignore keys that are already absent

For example:
a = False
if a:
    b = 0

del_keys_noerror(globals(), 'a', 'b')

Result: a gets deleted

P.S. I might add logging to log when a name is already undefined vs successfully deleted, just in case you need to debug the function.

@wjandrea:  Thanks.  I think this might be the most practical so far.  The other answers and comments demonstrate clever and lithe acrobatics that helped me with Python, but calling a function to delete from globals has the least amount of code overhead in the main body of code.

Something like
for name in [n for n in somelist if n in someplace]: del someplace[name]

should work

This works if someplace is an existing dict, but not for arbitrary named variables (globals() could be used in some cases, but locals() would only work in global scope, where it's equivalent to globals()).

I know, I leave this part open for the OP to fill in. The question was more about how to write a one-liner than about how to delete variables

Thanks, here is the code pattern that I found to work: for vNm in [ ifNm for ifNm in ['dog','cat','ifKeep1innerSpc'] if ifNm in globals() ]: del globals()[vNm].  This really consolidated my shaky grasp on list comprehension.

yes, this is exactly the same code pattern as the one I proposed

It doesn't delete the global variables (the names will still exist), but if your goal is just reclaiming the memory of the objects they refer to, there is a clever one-liner to set all such names to None (so referencing the name will still work, but will provide None, not whatever huge object used to be there):
globals().update(dict.fromkeys(("names", "to", "clear")))

dict.fromkeys takes an iterable of keys, and quickly makes a simple dict with those keys, mapping them all to None (if you pass a second argument, it will use that instead). globals().update(...) then bulk updates the globals dictionary. This will actually create variables if they didn't already exist (with the value None), but if your concern is reclaiming memory, not cleaning the global namespace of excess names (usually not important), this works just as well (and likely faster to boot, since it does the two operations in bulk at the C layer).

Thanks, but I'm actually trying to minimize the pollution in Spyder's Variable Explorer.  I keep a lot of DataFrame's around, so all the intermediate variables used to build them should be del'd.
